# Как сократить логическое выражение?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```
let message = "How are you? Eh, ok. Low or Lower? Ohhh."

function findWord(text) {

  let arrayLetters = text.split('');
  let result = [];

  arr.forEach(function(value, index, array) {

    if ( value == value.toUpperCase() && value != ' ' 
      && value != '?' && value != '.' && value != ',' ) {

      result.push(value);
    }
  }, 0);

  result = result.join('');
  console.log(message);
  console.log("Секретный текст: " + result);
}
```

Можно ли как нибудь переписать вот это условие в более короткий вариант?

```
if ( value == value.toUpperCase() && value != ' ' 
  && value != '?' && value != '.' && value != ',' ) {
```

Comment: смотря что вы хотите получить в итоге. Ведь вы же не написали этого

Comment: Меня интересует более короткая реализация данного условия  if ( value == value.toUpperCase() && value != ' ' 
      && value != '?' && value != '.' && value != ',' )

Comment: можно воспользоваться регуляркой

Comment: Это понятно..... но **ЧТО ВЫ ХОТИТЕ ПОЛУЧИТЬ В ИТОГЕ.** ?

Comment: Можно пример???

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я хочу получить тоже самое!!!!!! только с укороченным условием

Comment: ТОЖЕ САМОЕ это **ЧТО???** Вы реально не понимаете или придуриваетесь?

Comment: if ( value == value.toUpperCase() && value != ' ' && value != '?' && value != '.' && value != ',' ) <== **как переписать вот это условие в более короткий вариант?**

Comment: мде..... тяжело....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский В чем вы не можете разобраться ?

Comment: Вы хотите проверить что у нас строка состоящая только из заглавных букв или что?

Comment: Давайте спросим по-другому: **ЧТО ПОЛЕЗНОГО ДЕЛАЕТ ЭТО УСЛОВИЕ?** :)

Comment: Нужно в строке найти все заглавные буквы и конкатенировать их!

Comment: message.split('').filter(letter => letter.match(/[A-Z]/)).join('');

Comment: При использовании split(); заглавными так же почему-то являются все пробелы и символы(?,.)

Comment: То что это заглавная латинская буква я здесь проверяю .match([/A-Z]/)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму в этом сообществе видимо только вы меня понимаете)))

Comment: @Denisoed, ну Вы могли бы сразу русским языком написать что хотите, вам бы этот однострочник в секунду бы написали. Понимать что написано в коде, даже простом, требует некоторых усилий, проще сказать по-русски чего хотите. Можно и /[A-Z]/.test проверять как вам в ответе написали, в общем знакомьтесь с регулярками

Comment: `value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z'`

Comment: @Grundy, ага, или так, просто стоит предупредить автора, что когда появятся маленькие буквы, русские буквы включая Ё, логическое условие заметно раздуется

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, что вам нужно, но если задача — выбрать заглавные латинские буквы, то можно заменить то условие на:

```
if (/[A-Z]/.test(value)) {
```

Или вообще всю функцию на:

```
function findWord(text) {
  result = text.replace(/[^A-Z]+/g, '');
  console.log(message);
  console.log("Секретный текст: " + result);
}
```

Comment: Как это не очень понятно? Нужно `более короткая реализация данного условия if ( value == value.toUpperCase() && value != ' ' && value != '?' && value != '.' && value != ',' )` :D